# Problem with Overfull/Underfull and question: any function like \chaptherspath{}?

Tags: line-breaking, warnings

I am working with Texmaker.There are some issues i could not solve and maybe you can help me.

- First one is that when compiling the files with the main file, console returns three different errors:

First one is:

```
 Overfull \hbox (142.86594pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 51--52
\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 ser^^S^^Pa el pa^^S^^Ps con mas in-fec-ta-dos con Try-pa-no-zo-
ma cru-zi de Am^^Seri-ca[http://www.who.int/wer/2015/wer9006.pdf].
[]
```

Second one is:

```
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []
[11
]
LaTeX Info: Redefining \. on input line 59.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \% on input line 59.
[12]
```

- Second problem is the next:

In main document `thesis.tex` i have some chapters, everytime i write one of them should i specify the hole path? Is there any analogous function to '\graphicxpath{{}}' but for chapters?

My chapters part look like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[headheight=18pt,a4paper,width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{\vspace{-4.0cm}Study of \\~\\
    {\large Univers}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introducción}
\input{/capitulos/intro}

\chapter{Estado del arte}
\input{/capitulos/estado-del-arte}

\end{document}
```

So, i have a `thesis.tex` file and then in `/capitulos/chapter-files`
I do not know why it does not work.

Console returns:

```
Cap\'{\i }tulo 1.
! LaTeX Error: File `/capitulos/intro.tex' not found.
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: tex)
Enter file name:
! Emergency stop.
<read *>
l.48 \input{/capitulos/intro}
^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: For the overfull boxes: You can set the documentoption `draft`, with it the overfull lines will be marked with a black rectangle at the end of the line. This way you can easily spot them in the PDF (but with 100pt too wide, you should spot them without it, too). For your second issue: You can always specify relative paths to your `main.tex`. For whole chapters you might/should use `\include` rather than `\input`, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include)

Comment: Also the overfull boxes are no errors but warnings.

Comment: why do you need to give a path at all for your chapters? normally you would just use `\input{intro}` or `\input{chapters/intro}` if the main document is in a parent directory.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was confused with that from the beggining. I think it does not work for me :(

Comment: if you just say "it doesn't work" and don't say what you did or what error you get it is hard to help. It works for everyone else. I've been using latex for 30 years and I don't think I've ever used an absolute path in an input.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok. i will try and post if there is an error.

Comment: note it should be `\input{intro}`  not `\input{/intro}` unless `intro.tex` is at the root of the filesystem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, i think it is right. But it is not working. I edited again.

Comment: as I just said `\input{/capitulos/intro}` refers to a file at the root of the filesystem. just as if you typed `ls /capitulos/intro.tex` into a commandline it would fail. delete the first `/`  you need to specify a relative path from the working directory.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle oh, right. Thanks. I hadn't understand you. I edited to describe an underfull error that i could not fix.

Comment: @santimirandarp please don't keep changing the question. You already asked multiple unconnected questions in this slot. The site works best of you ask each question as a separate post.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes i am sorry. I have forgotten that question (but i had indicated it in the tittle of the post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that these are warnings not error.

You have a large url in the text `[http://www.who.int/wer/2015/wer9006.pdf]` that is not linebreaking, and so sticking in to the margin by 142.86594pt. (more or less 2 inches)

Use the `url` package and

```
\url{http://www.who.int/wer/2015/wer9006.pdf}
```

Then linebreaking will occur at the `/`

Comment: Thank you. It works. I edited a bit, please check the post